# SQL temptables Loop query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000

I have a temporary Table which looks like

TmpTable :

```
          ID(not unique)   Platform Name    OS    version 

           13                 UNIX          Ipad     5.1
           13                 Windows       Windows  2008
           14                 MAC           Ipad     4.1
```

Look_UP Tbl : for each of the above columns

```
    PlatformName LookuP Tbl: platform id  desc
                                 2        Unix
                                 5        windows

       OS Lookup            :  OS id    OSname
                                 4       Ipad

    Version Lookup          :  Version id  name
                                 5         5.1
```

Then Have EmpPlatformID , EmpOSID & EmpVersionID like below ;

```
       EmpPlatform  - EmpId  PltformNameID
                       13         1
                       13         6
       same for OS & ID
```

I need a query that
1) uses the lookup tables to get the corresponding ID for each column(PlatformName,OS,Version) for each of the employee id . 
2) Insert the ID for that empid in each of the actual tables .

So , empPlatformTable should look like ;

```
       EmpPlatform  - EmpId  PltformNameID
                       13         1
                       13         6
                       13         2    - new row added from tmptbl
                       13         5    - new row added from tmptbl
 The EmpOS & EmpVer also has similar column so the emp id should have corresponding IDs inserted from temptbl . please helps
```

EDIT:
Code to update PlatformName

```
Update EmpPN 
    Set EmpN.platform_id = PLookup.platform_id 
from #TempTable tmpd (READUNCOMMITTED) 
inner join EmpPlatform EmpPN (READUNCOMMITTED) 
    on EmpPN.emp_id = emp_id collate database_default 
inner join PlatformLookUpTbl PLookup(READUNCOMMITTED)
    on PLookup.[platform_name] = tmpd.PlatformName collate database_default
```

Comment: Could you post the code you have so far, and let us know where you are having issues with it?

Comment: I strongly suggest that when you think about solving these kinds of problem you stop thinking about the word "loop." There is nothing about this that would be optimized in any way by using a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Why not

```
Update EmpPN
Set 
Platform_ID = 
  (
    Select Top 1 L.Platform_ID From PlatformLookupTbl As L
    Inner Join #TempTable As T On L.PlatForm_Name = T.PlatFormName
    Where T.Emp_ID = EmpPN.Emp_ID
  ),
<next field> = 
  <analogous lookup statement>[,...]
```

If performance is bad, consider creating indices on your temp table to help out.

Comment: Unable to get the Solution . Can we use cursors?

Comment: @user1681514 Why do you want to use cursors?